# DOM tests with Mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

Is it possible to test if a window has been opened by a JS function with Mocha?

For example part of a test is to see whether a window to, say, Facebook, has been opened in order for a user to share the current app, so is it possible for Mocha to detect a window has been opened when I call `window.open(url, target)`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) returns `null` if the call fails, so as long as you have access to the return value in Mocha you can test whether or not it was successful.

Comment: D'oh! You're right. By using the window object I can (hopefully) work out the URL and check it's all good, good times.

Comment: That may or may not be the case. If you're opening a Facebook page in a window you'll be unable to access most of its properties due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Bah, I figured that, I'll just have to rework my JS to return the url should this be running in Node